# Service Now update()

Tags: servicenow

I want update problem state as closed when incident state is closed

I tried this code but it is updating all the records in problem table, But I want to update only that related table.

```
// update the state of all active incidents to 4 - "Awaiting User Info"
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident')
gr.addQuery('active', true);
gr.query();
gr.state = 4;
gr.updateMultiple();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Your question states that you want to update problems but in the code snippet you posted you make reference to the incident table. To update records in the problem table you would start your query with var gr = new GlideRecord('problem'); If you can provide more detail I may be able to provide additional help.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you could use a little glide scripting help. Try something more like this:

```
// update the state of all active incidents to 4 - "Awaiting User Info"
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident'); //Create the glide record
gr.addQuery('sys_id', current.incident_ref_field); //Only the relevant record should be returned.
gr.query();
if (gr.next()) {
    gr.state = 4;
    gr.update();
}
```

You only want the one related inc record, so we make sure that the returned record matches the record in the ref field (which I've called incident_ref_field, but you should change to the actual field name).